# CSS Selectors in Font Awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have the following code which is being styled using CSS Grid Layout. I want to display the icons as a single column when the window shrinks below a defined breakpoint (say, 500px). Because FA styles are, ahem..."unique" (Who puts spaces in class names?), which selector should I be targeting? Is `.fa-stack` appropriate here?

```
<ul class="social">
  <li><a href="https://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its not a space in the class name, its two classes `fa` and `fa-github`, the `fa` class selects the font the `fa-github` class selects the character. That said, I would target `fa` as this will be on all your font-awesome `i`

Comment: That aside, it is likely not the `i` elements themselves that make this display as multiple rows - but the `li` are, so you’d have to target them instead to begin with.

Comment: _“Is .fa-stack appropriate here?”_ - does counting the number of elements with that class in the HTML you have shown us not answer _that_ question itself already …?

Comment: +1 to CBroe: if grid container is `.social`, then the list items are the grid items. Links and `i` are descendants of those grid items, nothing special about them in regards to grid layout. OT: your links are considered empty (there's no content in them: no text or image with non-empty alternative, only an `aria-hidden="true"` element). You should [provide a link text that describes the purpose of a link for anchor elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H30.html) (visible or `visually-hidden` at least): essential for non-sighted users and good for SEO too

Comment: @FelipeAls I know about the empty items, the links themselves aren't important. I have ARIA related things in a separate branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spaces in classnames are seperators, because you can add multiple classes to one Element. In the case of `FontAwesome`, this means that `fa` is a single class, `fa-twitter` is a single class and `fa-2x` is another class, there is no such thing as spaces in classes.
Which one you want to select is now up to you, but if you want to apply it to all `FontAwesome` Elements, i would use the `.fa` class. If you want to apply it to a specific Icon, you should use the `.fa-twitter` (or `fa-github`, or ...).

So let's look at this example:

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

This Element has 3 classes, which you can give individual styles like this (all the styles below are applied to the `<i>` Tag!):

```
.fa {
    background: grey;
}

.fa-twitter {
    color: red;
}

.fa-2x {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Since you already mentioned, that classes with spaces would be not the best idea, this would obviusly not work as intended

```
.fa .fa-twitter .fa-2x {
    background: grey;
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

because this would only apply to an Element of the class `fa-2x`, which has a parent element element of the class `fa-twitter`, which has a parent element of the class `fa`.

Answer (score 0):

The .fa class sets the display and the following fa-* classes match the icon and size.

You should set your required styles to override .fa and then use media queries to manage styles for the other breakpoints.

Comment: `.fa` does not set position, it sets the font and rendering style.

Comment: It sets the display which is what I meant, now corrected.